# How to import a Windows.UI.dll in a console application using Reflection and Visual Studio

Tags: c#, dll, system.reflection

I am using a Visual Studio 2017 Community Version to develop a console application using Reflection. I want to analyse the dll file of Windows.UI.Notifications using Reflection.
However, when I try to load the dll file using Assembly.LoadFrom("path") , the program throws an error given below.

> System.BadImageFormatException: "Could not load file or assembly '(path)' or one of it's dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest."

I am working on a Windows 10 64 bit system. I have tried loading the dll from System32 folder , SystemWOW64 and also from ProgramFiles(x86) directly. I also tried to copy the dll from these folders to a different folder. But each time the error is thrown while loading the assembly. I am able to load Xamarin dlls using the same methods.

Comment: These UWP dlls were written in C++, not a .NET language.  That you can use them anyway in a UWP app written in C# is because they are actually COM servers.  The windows.winmd reference that such a project uses is the type library for them.  So no, Assembly.LoadFrom() is never going to work.

Comment: Is there any way in which these dlls can be used using reflection?

Answer (score 1):

In order to use `Assembly.LoadFrom(path)`, dll file must be .Net assembly but in your case Windows.UI.dll is not a .Net assembly but native code. You can not use `Assembly.LoadFrom(path)`.

If you want to use Windows.UI.dll in your .net application please refer to [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh779727.aspx#sending_toast_notifications_from_desktop_apps)

Comment: The path specified in the answer contains System dlls. I am importing the dll of the Windows native API. I dont need System.Windows.*.dll , but i want to import Windows.UI.dll. Can you help me in this regards? Thank you!

Comment: I see you have edited your question a bit. Are you trying to Load  Windows.UI.dll?

Comment: Yes , I am trying to load Windows.UI.dll.

Comment: Can you please clarify if Xamarin.Forms.dll is a .NET assembly? Because I am able to load the dll using Assembly.LoadFrom()

Comment: @neelr, You can use ilspy, http://www.ilspy.net to see the inners of a .Net assembly. Yes Xamarin is .Net assembly